# Exact size of Application is size or sizeHint

Tags: qt, size, qwidget, sizehint

I have set the,

```
setGeometry(0,0,1280,760);
setMaximumSize(1280,760);
setMinimumSize(1280,760);
```

Now when I am printing size and sizeHint, I am getting

> size : QSize(1280, 760)
>
> sizeHint : QSize(970, 752)

Which is exact size of my application, How can I change the size and size exactly to 1280X760 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size hint is only a recommended size for widget which are inside QLayout. It does not affect windows widgets, which is in your case your application window.

However if you want to have a different size hint, you need to reimplement `sizeHint()`.

```
QSize MyAppWindow:sizeHint() const
{
   return QSize(1280, 760);
}
```